# Slice an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
print_r($myarray);

Array ( [0] => text one ) Array ( [0] => text two ) Array ( [0] => text three ) ...
```

When i use slice

```
print_r(array_slice($myarray,1,2));

Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) ......
```

I get an empty array, how can i slice this array in half?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You actually have an array that contains arrays which probably might be what is causing the issue for you. Though I do not see how you get the result you posted... It mighty be that you actually apply the slice function to each element of the output array. Then certainly you will get an empty array for each iteration. As to be expected, since each element you iterate over contains only a single element. So slicing from position 1 will result in an empty array each time...

Consider this simple example using a plain array:

```
<?php
$input = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
$output = array_slice($input, 1, 2);
print_r($output);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => two
    [1] => three
)
```

So php's `array_slice()` function works just as expected...

---

Same with an array of arrays as you suggest in your post:

```
<?php
$input = [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"], ["five"], ["six"]];
$output = array_slice($input, 1, 2);
print_r($output);
```

The output of that is, as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => two
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => three
        )

)
```

---

Also considering your second comment below, that you have some words in a single string (which *mighty* be what you describe) I get a meaningful result myself:

```
<?php
$input = explode(' ', "one two three four five six");
$output = array_slice($input, 1, 2);
print_r($output);
```

The output, as expected, is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => two
    [1] => three
)
```

Comment: I convert string to array like this: 

` $myarray = $product["model_number"]; `
`  $myarray= explode(', ', $myarray); `

How can i changed the array index? 
Thanks

Comment: @Edo I cannot answer to that since I don't know the structure of `$product["model_number"]`.

Comment: When i do 
 `print_r($product["model_number"]);`
I get:
`one two three four`
Strings in one line together

Comment: @Edo I added a third variant to demonstrate that slicing is not your issue. You really need to find out what data structure you actually have. Why do you explode by `', '` if you claim to have a string separated by only whitespaces?

Comment: The output of `$product["model_number"]` in face it like this:
**number onenumber twonumber three**
i have a string from 2/3 words, the last word of the first and the first of the next string is connected.

How to covert this string to array correctly?

Comment: @Edo Even that won't lead to the output you posted... But anyway: how should code determine the limit of words if there is nothing in between? Do not try to _guess_ the data you actually have, find out what _exactly_ you have. Dump the data into a log file or something. Without knowing your actual input there is little sense in implementing any processing logic.

Comment: The print_r returns the strings as i commented above.
The last character of the first string is connected with the first character for the next string.

2 strings Number One, Number Two
Print_r will return:

Number OneNumber Two

Comment: @Edo Sorry, but there is nothing more I can say. What you claim does not match what you posted, what you claim does not result in the output you posted. We cannot help if it is totally unclear what data you have and what processing steps you perform. Example: your `explode()` call does not git to _any_ of the variants of data you claimed to actually have. What should we make of that?

Comment: I just want to fix my problem, i know that i might not have describe it maybe perfectly, im new the stack overflow. 
The problem is the `explode()` i have not converted the array propertly.
With `$myarray= explode(', ', $myarray);` i cant slice the array later. Since it has not converted string to array propertly.

Comment: Stop claiming functions do not work correctly. It is you who does not know and apparently fail to find out what data you actually have. Not php's fault, not some functions's fault. Find out what data you have. I already suggested to dump the data into a log file to be able to examine it. Did you do that? No? _Why not?_ Alternatively use your browsers console to examine the data it actually received.